# Design pattern for providing data with custom parameters

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to design a framework that allows various workers to request values from a central data source given arbitrary parameters. Consider the following:

A worker requests the current value of a moving average calculated from the previous 7 time periods. It does so by passing the following to some central data source or provider:

```
{ 
  Name: 'MovingAverage',
  Parameters: {
    Periods: 7,
    RemoveBias: true,
  }
}
```

The central data source / provider has `MovingAverage` registered in some manner, along with the acceptable range of parameters that can be used in the calculation of the moving average. Given what was passed, the data source calculates the moving average with the specified parameters and passes the result back to the worker.

This seems fairly straightforward in theory, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to architect something like this.

**I am wondering if there are any established design patterns or open-source examples that implement something like this so that I can study them and implement them into my project.**

I don't know what a seasoned developer would call something like this, so I am stuck in terms of planning my course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to implement this would be using [the command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) where you would define a new class (command) for each type of fetch.

In this case, you would have a MovingAverageCommand class, with Periods and RemoveBias as properties.

Now, how you apply the command depends on many factors, but a standard way to do it would be to define an execute method that would receive an instance of your datasource.

```
public class MovingAverageCommand : IDataSourceCommand {
    int _periods
    bool _removeBias

    [...]

    public Response Execute(IDataSource dataSource) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My point of view for your case:

1. Need a way to parse the request.
2. Need a layer/service/class whatever name above the central data source.

For the first point as @Phil-R said, you can use a command pattern.

and for the second point you can use a repository pattern.